# Is it possible to install NServiceBus nodes on an attached virtual disk drive in a VM?

Tags: windows-services, virtual-machine, nservicebus, windows-server-2008-r2, vhd

The server in question, a Server 2008 R2 VM, has very little space left on the C: drive, but has an attached virtual disk drive with 30GB unused. With some research, I found that installing Windows services from an attached virtual drive is possible, but the registration keys will be lost if Windows is reinstalled.

Is it possible to install the NServiceBus services from the attached virtual disk drive? If so, are there any other concerns about NServiceBus operation that I should be aware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attached disk is just a disk that gets mounted like any other disk.  What is important is that the mounting takes place before the service is started. So make sure that windows service is dependent on the correct services.

You can set dependencies by using the commandline tool `sc.exe` which is explained here:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed

As you are using NServiceBus it could be that that service is dependent on MSMQ or MSDTC or maybe a local SQL Server instance. All of these can be added so that the windows service will be started after the other services are running.

If the 'attached disk' is configured by the VM host then you don't have to worry about mounting at all.